# TSQL select from XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
   ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)'),
   COUNT(B.[userID]) AS totalLikes
FROM   
   @likeXML.nodes('/likes/like') AS ParamValues(x1)
JOIN 
   apsLikes AS B ON B.[likeID] = ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)')
FOR XML PATH ('likeData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

However this returns an error

> Column 'ParamValues.x1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I try and add it to the group by it says XML cannot be used in the group by clause.

What would be the correct way to format this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried maybe using a CTE?  Give the first column an alias, and remove the COUNT... like this:

```
; WITH XmlResults AS (
SELECT 
   ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') AS likeId,
   B.[userID] AS totalLikes
FROM   
   @likeXML.nodes('/likes/like') AS ParamValues(x1)
JOIN 
   apsLikes AS B ON B.[likeID] = ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)')
FOR XML PATH ('likeData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
)
SELECT likeId, COUNT(totalLikes)
FROM XmlResults
GROUP BY likeId
```

Comment: I gave this a shot (didnt think of doing it this way) but got this error? `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'XmlResults'.`

Comment: Sorry, not having the schema it's hard for me to test locally... if you just run the select inside the With(), does every column properly have a name?

Comment: For some reason I get the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@likeXML".` when I run it even though my var is already declared?

Comment: You'd need the declaration of your "@likeXML" selected with the SELECT statement.  Again, it's really hard for me to help when I don't have all the schema, data, and can't see what you're typing :-(  IF you run your original query above, giving the first column an alias gives all the resulting rows column names, correct?  I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working for you.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to do a nested select, like this:

```
SELECT LikeId, COUNT(Userid) FROM (
    SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') LikeId,
           B.[userID] Userid
    FROM   @likeXML.nodes('/likes/like') AS ParamValues(x1)
    JOIN apsLikes AS B
    ON B.[likeID] = ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)')
    FOR      XML PATH ('likeData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
    ) tmp
Group By LikeId
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a subquery and then grouping and XML'it should work :

```
select x1, count(Likes) from
(
SELECT 
   ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') AS X1,
   B.[userID] AS Likes
FROM   
   @likeXML.nodes('/likes/like') AS ParamValues(x1)
JOIN 
   apsLikes AS B ON B.[likeID] = ParamValues.x1.value('likeID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)')
) t
group by X1
FOR XML PATH ('likeData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```